# Connecting PHP5/Apache2.2 with SSPI Auth on MSSQL Server 2000?

Tags: php, apache, sql-server-2000

Well, basically thats the scenario:

I need to reach a MS SQL Server 2000 database where I was granted access using the NT(LPAD) authentication to my user.

But, my plattaform is a PHP5/Apache2.2 on Windows XP and I got no way to make my authentication on SQL Server.

I've tried direct connection using:

```
msql_connect("serverip", "user", "password");
```

using

```
mssql.secure_connection = Off
```

no success.

Tried also with and without user/pwd and secure_connection On/Off.
All throwing error of login failed.

Secondly, tried to use an odbc connection.
Set up on System DNS and tested with success (on DNS configuration dialog).
Then on php I set connection to:

```
odbc_connect("dnsName", "user", "password");
```

also with/without user/pwd, failling on all tries. (Here, i've tried to change some of the DNS configuration but no success).

Well, thirdly I was researching no sspi modules for apache authentication on Win32 but couldn't dowload the module for tests. Also I'm not sure anymore if it is possible to cross this microsoft bridge.

So any suggestions (even if the best way was to give up) is appreciate.

**PS: Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Ok, not tested yet but since no one aswered here's my try out.

For this to work you must set the Apache Service on Server with the correct privileges to make the auth.

This is made into the administrative tools -> services -> rigth click on Apache service.

There's a tab where you must set the logon for the service. Set this to your win user account and restart the sevice (stop and start).

The tip here is not to use the Apache monitor to do that but to stop and start service on the admin tools itself.

Hope it helps someone.